# Erro de jQuery não visível quando migro código

Tags: jquery, html, css3

Bom, tenho na seguinte página

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/aa2.php

O script funcional

Já quando eu migro para o final da pagina:

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/index.php

Então ocorrem os seguintes erros:

1 ) Não consigo mais clicar nas **li's**

2 ) Já não aparece o efeito de **pointer** (mãozinha) ao passar o mouse sobre as **li's**

Já tentei de tudo mas não estou conseguindo.

E ainda tem outra coisa:

http://www.hotplateprensas.com.br/estilos/aa2.php

Não funciona no `chrome`, só no firefox

Eis aqui o código do aa2.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="_js/jquery.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
}
body {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 800px;
}
.selectOptions select {
    display: none;
}
.selectOptions .selectOption:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    display: block;
    top: 1px;
    right: 1px;
    width: 33px;
    height: 33px;
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption.setaBaixo:after {
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaBaixo.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption.setaCima:after {
    background-image: url(_imgs/setaCima.jpg);
}
.selectOptions .selectOption, ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}
.selectOptions ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: -1;
}
.selectOptions ul li {
    width: 100%;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 31px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 2px;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-color: rgb(240,240,240);
    border-bottom: rgba(0,0,0,.1) 1px solid;
}
.selectOptions ul li:hover {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
}
.selectOptions ul li:hover + .selectOption:after {
    color: rgba(0,0,0, .1);
    background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="selectOptions">
  <select name="select" required>
    <option value="1">um</option>
    <option value="2">dois</option>
    <option value="3">Tres</option>
  </select>
  <div class="selectOption">
    <ul>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

  $(".selectOptions select").css("display", "none");

  contador = 0;

  $(".selectOptions .selectOption").click( function() {

      if(contador % 2 == 0) {
          $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow", "visible") ;
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaCima").removeClass("setaBaixo");
      } else {
           $(".selectOptions ul").css("overflow", "hidden");         
          $(".selectOptions .selectOption").addClass("setaBaixo").removeClass("setaCima");
      }

      $('.selectOptions .selectOption ul li').click(function(){ 
      alert();    
           $($(this).closest('ul')).prepend($(this)); 

           $(".selectOptions select option").filter(function() {
              return $(this).val() == $('.selectOptions .selectOption ul li').val();
           }).prop("selected", true);

      })

      contador++;
  }); 


  $(".selectOptions select > option").each(function() {
      $(".selectOptions .selectOption ul").append("<li id="+this.value+">"+this.text+"</li>");
  });

});
```

Uma coisa que observei é que na index.php, quando chega aqui:

```
$('.selectOptions .selectOption ul li').click(function(){ 
  alert();
```

Não entra na **função**, pode colocar uma **alert** na primeira linha que não alerta. 
Pode deixar só **alert** dentro da função que nada acontece.

Isso para ambos os navegadores, **chrome** e **firefox**.

No entanto, para o arquivo **aa2.php**, o erro só ocorre para o **chrome**.

Mas outra coisa que notei é que no `css`, **cursor:pointer** não está funcionando para a página **index.php** nos 2 navegadores já na página **aa2.php** o cursor funciona.

Comment: Você está utilizando modo do compatibilidade de navegador no seu css `-webkit-` e `-moz-`?

Comment: como assim? Dá uma explicação fazendo favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
*No print acima, quando passo o ponteiro de selecionar elementos sobre o menu, ele seleciona o body (em azul) em vez de selecionar o menu.*

Seu problema está no `z-index` negativo abaixo, que está jogando a `<ul>` pra trás do `body`:

```
.selectOptions ul {
    overflow: hidden;
    list-style: none;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Apague a linha `z-index: -1;` que irá funcionar no Chrome também.

Comment: não consegui enxergar que o menu está por traz. Você consegue me passar uma print dessa tela fazendo favor?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Botei um print na resposta.

Comment: Entendi, note que você está passando o mouse sobre a **ul** aberta e da segunda opção em diante. Nesse caso, você está em cima de um pseudo elemento **afer** que ainda não está no dom. Por isso o **inspector** marca o **body**. Acho que é isso. Mas eu gostaria que você me enviasse é daquele detalhe do inicio do **post** onde você diz que a **div** está por cima do **menu**

Comment: @CarlosRocha Pois é. No Chrome o menu está por baixo, por isso que ele não funciona. Com z-index eu consegui trazer ele pra cima e funcionou. No Firefox funcionou sem o z-index. Isso significa que seu código não está muito bom. É muito difícil acontecer incompatibilidades entre navegadores para coisas simples assim. Quando isso ocorre, é sinal de que o código não está legal.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Seu problema está no CSS `.selectOptions ul` com `z-index: -1;`... Tira isso que irá funcionar.

Comment: Eu fiz isso com o objetivo de não permitir seleção sobre o primeiro elemento e funcionou. Mas funcionou de forma errada né/ Isso era pra ser um select option

Comment: @CarlosRocha exatamente.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Se quiser desabilitar a primeira opção para click, é só mudar a linha `$('.selectOptions .selectOption ul li:not(:eq(0))').click(function(){`

Comment: funcionou! Obrigado!

Comment: Rapaz, resolveu um problema e criou outro. Agora, as duas setas não estão se alterando com o after, isto é, só está aparecendo a seta para baixo. Atualizei lá no servidor. Se puder dar uma olhada fazendo favor?

Comment: @CarlosRocha No CSS, as duas últimas classes precisam estar unidas, assim: `.selectOptions .selectOption.setaCima:after`. Veja que não pode haver um espaço entre as duas últimas classes. Faça o mesmo na linha onde tem `.setaBaixo`.

Comment: Sim deu certo. Obrigado. Mas diz aê, ficou legal o projetozinho dessa select option que eu criei? Precisa dar uma melhorada no visual né?

Comment: @CarlosRocha Ficou legal. To tentando bolar o efeito "rolo" que vc disse na outra pergunta.

Comment: então, achei outro problema tb. kkk, quando eu cliko fora da ul, gostaria de que fechasse ela, fizesse  overflow:hidden, mas nada que tentei deu certo. Na verdade até deu certo, mas atrapalha outras coisas.

Comment: @CarlosRocha Vou ver isso tb. Mas gostaria de saber se posso botar o link do site lá na outra pergunta pra minha resposta ter referência de código.

Comment: mas é claro que pode. O problema é que assim que terminar, precisarei excluir pois o site não é meu, É de cliente. Mas pode sim.,

Comment: @CarlosRocha O lance de clicar fora e fechar o menu, adiciona isso acima da linha onde tem `contador++`: e.stopPropagation();

Comment: @CarlosRocha Melhor ver o código todo neste Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vjzogcw9/1/